# DataTables: Server-side formatting

Tags: json, datatables, datatables-1.10, jquery-datatables-editor

My DataTable is loaded almost entirely from the server side and I would like to keep as much processing as possible on the server to **reduce the workload** on the client.

By formatting I mean changing color, size, font, font-weight, adding icons and html tags... For example when a row or a few cells need to be highlighted or displayed in a specific way.

I'm thinking about using the `render` parameter, but I didn't find a way to set it in JSON:

```
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) }
```

An example would also be the following snippet, but it does not provide enough separation between the client and server:

```
{
    "doc": "<strong>546546545<strong>",
    "nothing": 0.0,
    "order": "<div class="shipped">98745</div>"
}
```

While I was able to find resources on how to fetch data from the server, I can't find information on how to pass formatting data as part of the `json`.

Is there a way to paste formatting options in my current DataTable format to make it also optimal? What alterations need to be done?

http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/1004/

JSON:

```
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "doc",
            "title": "Doc."
        },
        {
            "data": "order",
            "title": "Order no."
        },
        {
            "data": "nothing",
            "title": "Nothing"
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "doc": "564251422",
            "nothing": 0.0,
            "order": "56421"
        },
        {
            "doc": "546546545",
            "nothing": 0.0,
            "order": "98745"
        }
    ]
}
```

JS:

```
this.table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    data: json.rows,
                    columns: json.columns,
                    select: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    rowReorder: true,
                    colReorder: true,
                    scrollY: 680,
                    deferRender: true,
                    scroller: true
                });
```

HTML:

```
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%" />
```

Comment: can you please include datatable declaration code in question?

Comment: it is included now in the updated question